# Building an iOS-like Photo Viewer on a Mobile Site

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, pinchzoom

I am building a mobile site and one of the features required by my client is an iOS like photo viewer for his products' photos.

Each product has 3-4 photos. I want to be able to scroll through them with gestures and pinch-and-zoom on each one of them.

I started implementing it using the hammer.js library but I am not sure if it's what I need.

Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know hammer.js but I've found that iScroll will let you achieve all of this with minimal effort: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4